# Select set of columns so that each row has at least one non-NA entry

Tags: r, dataframe, subset, na

I have a large number of variables (columns), but each has missing values for some of the observations (rows). How can I get a set (or all sets) of columns so that each row has at least one non-NA value?

Example:

```
> df <- data.frame(a=c(1,NA,NA,1,NA), b=c(NA,1,NA,1,NA), c=c(1,NA,NA,NA,1), d=c(1,1,1,1,NA))
> df
   a  b  c  d
1  1 NA  1  1
2 NA  1 NA  1
3 NA NA NA  1
4  1  1 NA  1
5 NA NA  1 NA
```

Here I would like to obtain columns `c` and `d`, as these combined result in at least one non-NA observation for each row. I thought of brute-forcing all possible variable combinations, but it is not feasible in my case given a large number of variables. Is there a more efficient solution?

Comment: Do you mean the *minimum* set of columns with at least one non NA?

Comment: practically, I'm trying to get a better view of the data, and the minimum set is I think one way there. I think in the actual data there could also be multiple column sets of the minimum length as different variable combinations might lead to at least one non-zero entry per row, also perhaps sets that have more variables than the minimum set might still be insightful. So any help with finding column sets, minimum or other, is much appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using a `while` loop, this should work to get the minimum set of variables with at least one non-NA per row.

```r
best <- function(df){
  best <- which.max(colSums(sapply(df, complete.cases)))
  while(any(rowSums(sapply(df[best], complete.cases)) == 0)){
    best <- c(best, which.max(sapply(df[is.na(df[best]), ], \(x) sum(complete.cases(x)))))
  }
  best
}
```

testing

```r
best(df)
#d c 
#4 3

df[best(df)]
#   d  c
#1  1  1
#2  1 NA
#3  1 NA
#4  1 NA
#5 NA  1
```

First, select the column with the least NAs (stored in `best`). Then, update the vector with the column that has the highest number of non-NA rows on the remaining rows (where best has still NAs), until you get every rows with a complete case.

Comment: Thanks, that works! I just did a little change to your function: 
```best <- c(best, which.max(sapply(df[apply(is.na(df[best]), 1, all), ],  \(x) sum(complete.cases(x)))))``` since in the original function I would get an error (```Subscript `is.na(df[best])` must be a simple vector, not a matrix.```)